# Certain parameters returns function error using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

The code below was supposed to return my application private and public keys. When I run the code, only the private keys gets alerted and successfully.

The publickey throws error 
**TypeError: u.getPublickKeyFromPrivate is not a function**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
ProfileData
} from 'bacoma';

const bacoma = require( 'bacoma' );
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {

      },
publicKey:  "",

    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.recordedData();
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    const { userSession } = this.props;
    this.setState({
    });
  }


recordedData() {

const { userSession } = this.props
var appkeyPrivate =    userSession.appPrivateKey;
alert('am privatekey: ' +appkeyPrivate);

var publicKey =    bacoma.getPublickKeyFromPrivate(appkeyPrivate);

alert('am pubick key: ' +publicKey);
console.log('iam publick key: ' +publicKey);

  }

  render() {
    const {userSession } = this.props;

    return (
      // returned content here
    );
  }
}
```

Any idea on what could be the problem

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by appending userSession to the properties

```
var publicKey =    userSession.getPublickKeyFromPrivate(appkeyPrivate);
```